# RDF4J not filtering TreeModel in expected way

Tags: scala, rdf, owl, rdf4j

I have a TTL with something like

```
ex:isDataProperty rdf:type owl:DatatypeProperty .

ex:Article  a       owl:Class ;
        owl:hasKey  ( ex:isDataProperty ) .
```

And when I load the model with RDF4J (as a TreeModel) then try to filter to extract the properties annotated with haskey fails (just returns empty list result)

Some samples that return data:

```
val dataProperties = model.filter(null, RDF.TYPE, OWL.DATATYPEPROPERTY).subjects().asScala
val classes = model.filter(null, RDF.TYPE, OWL.CLASS).subjects().asScala
```

The sample I want, that doesn't return data:

```
    val propertiesWithKeys = model.filter(null, RDF.PROPERTY, OWL.HASKEY).subjects().asScala
```

I have tried a few variations of the previous one using RDF.TYPE or RDF.Value. (instead of RDF.PROPERTY)

Comment: Why do you use `model.filter(null, RDF.PROPERTY, OWL.HASKEY)`? I mean, the predicate itself is `OWL.HASKEY`, so it should be `model.filter(null, OWL.HASKEY, null)` to get all triples with this predicate

Comment: and the property isn't "annotated" with it. The property is used as key. The RDF triple is `ex:Article owl:hasKey  ( ex:isDataProperty ) .` - that also means, the property itself is an object in the triple which in fact is a list because it can be a composite key in OWL. So `model.filter(null, OWL.HASKEY, null).objects()` will lead to nodes representing RDF collections. How to convert back those RDF collections can be found here: https://rdf4j.eclipse.org/documentation/programming/model/#rdf-collections - so use `RDFCollections.asValues` or `RDFCollections.getCollection` with the arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you're after is any subject that has a `owl:hasKey` property, regardless of value. So both the subject and the object are wildcards, you just want to filter by property name. The way to do that is like this:

```
model.filter(null, OWL.HASKEY, null)
```

Now, furthermore you say that you want to know the properties that have been used as annotation using this `owl:hasKey` property. In your example, that would be  `ex:isDataProperty`. Note that in your model, this is not the subject of the `owl:hasKey` relation - it's in the object values:

```
model.filter(null, OWL.HASKEY, null).objects()
```

To further complicate matters, the object values in your example are not simply single values. Instead, each class is annotated using a *list* of properties, so the object value is a list object (a.k.a. an RDF Collection). To process this list, there are some utility methods provided by the `Models` and `RDFCollections` classes.

For each of the objects you can do this to get the actual list of values:

```
RDFCollections.asValues(model, objectNode, new ArrayList<Value>())
```

(where `objectNode` is one of the values that `.objects()` returned)

**Edit** since `objects()` returns objects of type `Value` and `RDFCollections` expects a `Resource`, you'll either have to do a cast, or if you want to do all of this in a fluent way, you can use `Models.objectResources` instead. The whole thing then becomes:

```
Models.objectResources(model.filter(null, OWL.HASKEY, null))
        .asScala.map(o => RDFCollections.asValues(model, o, new ArrayList[Value]()));
```

(I may have the Scala-specific bits of this wrong, but you get the gist hopefully)

For more information on how to work with the rdf4j Model API and with RDF Collections, see the [rdf4j documentation](https://rdf4j.eclipse.org/documentation/programming/model/).

Comment: Thanks, btw, when I use model.filter(null, OWL.HASKEY, null).subjects().asScala.map(o => org.eclipse.rdf4j.model.util.RDFCollections.asValues(model, o, new java.util.ArrayList[org.eclipse.rdf4j.model.Value]())) I get an error of "rdf4j list not well formed rdf:first statement missing", any tip?

Comment: thanks, the prob is with .objects doesn't compile, RDFCollection.asValues 2nd arg expect a org.eclipse.rdf4j.model.Resource not a Value

Comment: `Resource` is a subclass of `Value`. You'll have to cast it. Or use [`Models.objectResources(model.filter(null, OWL.HASKEY, null))`](https://rdf4j.eclipse.org/javadoc/latest/org/eclipse/rdf4j/model/util/Models.html#objectResources-org.eclipse.rdf4j.model.Model-) instead.

Comment: Right both Resource & Value have the same members. Thanks.